# Periods in time with high density of error (in a data frame)

Tags: python, pandas, probability-density

I have a data frame which has a timestamp column and an error column, the error column has 6 type of values (NaN, D, E, F, G, H) and I need to extract periods in time with high density of error E and I don't know how to approach this.

[image]

[image]

My approach would be creating a histogram and then I could calculate a density of probability for every error, then I would iterate all the days and select those with highest probability for E.

Are there any approaches for this type of problems? thanks for your time

Comment: You have a timestamp column; how is the *day* information encoded there? Also, can you please share the data as text e.g., `print(df.to_dict())`'s output would suffice. Along with the desired output.

Comment: Edited! I have used a dictionary to transform NaN into 0, and E into 2.

Comment: Thanks but neither the data is copy-pastable as it is in image form nor you shared the desired output (which can be image no problem)... You don't have to share the whole data of yours (in fact better not!); so-called [mcve] will do e.g., `print(df.head(20).to_dict())` *and* the corresponding desired output. Otherwise people here need to construct the frames on their own, line by line to test the possible solutions...

Comment: Of course there might exist people who don't need any data to test the solution and write it away (i'm not one of them :ğ) but you know... increasing possibilities is better perhaps.

Comment: {'timestamp': {413: Timestamp('2019-11-10 00:00:00'), 1008: Timestamp('2019-11-10 03:09:14.769846564'), 145: Timestamp('2019-11-10 06:18:29.539693128'), 1467: Timestamp('2019-11-10 09:27:44.309539693'), 1480: Timestamp('2019-11-10 12:36:59.079386257')}, 'error': {413: 3.0, 1008: 2.0, 145: 0.0, 1467: 0.0, 1480: 2.0}, 'feature1': {413: 0, 1008: 1, 145: 1, 1467: 0, 1480: 1}, 'feature2': {413: 3, 1008: 3, 145: 3, 1467: 2, 1480: 4}, 'feature3': {413: 1, 1008: 2, 145: 0, 1467: 0, 1480: 1}}

Comment: `df.groupby(df.timestamp.dt.date).error.apply(lambda s: s.eq(2).sum() / s.size)` This is supposed to give you the densities; is it giving it? We group by the date and apply a function to `error`s that takes the ratio of 2's in the group. After this, you can chain `idxmax` to get the date with highest error density, or with `nlargest(n)` to get the highest `n` ones.

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried splitting the table into individual days using resample('D', on = 'timestamp') method and it worked but I couldn't apply lambda expression like you did using groupby method!

Comment: glad you made it run! do you mind if I post it as an answer below so that issue may be closed?

Comment: Sure thing! I also need to specify advantages / disadvantages and how this could be improved. I guess an advantage is the flexibility this provides

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way:

```
df.groupby(df.timestamp.dt.date).error.apply(lambda s: s.eq(2).sum() / s.size)
```

We group by the date of the timestamps and apply a function to `error`s that takes the ratio of 2's in the group. After this, you can chain `idxmax` to get the date with highest error density, or with `nlargest(n)` to get the highest n ones.

With the sample data provided, this gives:

```
timestamp
2019-11-10    0.4
Name: error, dtype: float64
```

(since there is only 1 day, only it appears.)